# Python GPT4ALL model loading twice using multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

This program runs fine, but the model loads every single time "generate_response_as_thanos" is called, here's the general idea of the program:

```
`gpt4_model = GPT4All('ggml-model-gpt4all-falcon-q4_0.bin', allow_download=False)
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.setProperty('rate', 150)
def generate_response_as_thanos(afterthanos):
    output = gpt4_model.generate("You respond to the question as Thanos from Marvel." + afterthanos)
    print(output)
    engine.say(output)
    engine.runAndWait()`

`def main():
while True:
if 'thanos' in text_lower:
index = text_lower.index('thanos')
       words_after_thanos = text_lower[index + 6:]
       engine.say("One moment master")
       engine.runAndWait()
       response_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=generate_response_as_thanos,
                                                                       args=(words_after_thanos,))
       response_process.start()`
```

I've been stuck on this issue for a couple days now, I've tried using different modules, and encapsulating the function better, but the problem is that when I encapsulate the function, I get some type of "pickled error" that stems from multiprocessing.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The model loads every time you run `GPT4All`, which will run in every subprocess.  Just like the instructions tell you, your global operations (like that) need to be inside an `if __name__=="__main__":` block.